# Do multiple processes writing with O_APPEND overwrite data?

Tags: python, linux, file, append

I know mode O_APPEND is atomic mode , then lseek and write is atomic , but I think if multiple processes write to one log they will overwrite each other's data.

Although O_APPEND is the atomic operation, but the two processes have set lseek at the same time, then next to write log, This will happen to overwrite the data.

Comment: What's the maximum amount you're writing in a single call?

Comment: There will be no overwriting (data loss). If you think there will be when there are processes writing in parallel, you don't understand the meaning of "atomic" in this context - the whole point is that the seek and the write behave as if they happened simultaneously. (And in actual implementation, there is no seek in the first place.) What can happen, though, is that the output of the processes is interleaved. This is much more likely if the amount of output to be written in a single call is large.